# ios google analytic 3.03 out of memory

Tags: google-analytics, out-of-memory

google analytics out of memory in ios?

My project was to apply the google Analytic 3.03 version.

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

// This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with
// hits until it is set to a new value or to nil.

// page is string param
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:page];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

this is image...
http://i41.tinypic.com/25rnuh4.jpg

because of last line method

```
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

this log message :

malloc: *** mmap(size=1291476992) failed (error code=12)

WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.03 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:49): Uncaught exception: Out of memory. We suggest restarting the application. If you have an unsaved document, create a backup copy in Finder, then try to save.

VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.03 -[GAIRequestBuilder requestGetUrl:payload:] (GAIRequestBuilder.m:177): building URLRequest for https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect

VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.03 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher dispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:503): Sending hit(s)

INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.03 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:157): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200

INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.03 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:430): hit(s) Successfully dispatched

INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.03 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:167): 1 hit(s) sent

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSMallocException', reason: 'Out of memory. We suggest restarting the application. If you have an unsaved document, create a backup copy in Finder, then try to save.'
*** First throw call stack:

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x044585e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x039b18b6 objc_exception_throw + 44

2   Foundation                          0x0368a4a1 _NSOutOfMemoryErrorHandler + 72

3   CoreFoundation                      0x043d9488 __CFStringChangeSizeMultiple + 1704

4   CoreFoundation                      0x043dc4ae CFStringAppend + 318

5   CoreFoundation                      0x043d6e03 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8611

6   CoreFoundation                      0x0447a1d5 _CFStringAppendFormatAndArgumentsAux + 69

7   CoreFoundation                      0x0447a179 -[__NSCFString appendFormat:] + 89

8   MyApp                            0x000d1a4a -[NSDictionary(Description) descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 762

9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x039c3874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77

10  MyApp                            0x0000be1d -[NSObject(Description) descriptionForObject:locale:indent:] + 397

11  MyApp                            0x000d1a0b -[NSDictionary(Description) descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 699

12  CoreFoundation                      0x04453ce0 -[NSDictionary descriptionWithLocale:] + 48

13  Foundation                          0x035ce785 _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 93

14  CoreFoundation                      0x043d6dc6 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8550

15  CoreFoundation                      0x04417944 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 116

16  Foundation                          0x035cd690 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 143

17  Foundation                          0x035ce70d +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 88

18  Myapp                            0x00295b64 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] + 342


19  MyApp                            0x00296f9a -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueDispatch:] + 538

20  MyApp                            0x00296d68 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueModel:] + 146

21  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x039c381f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70

22  Foundation                          0x036069d8 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 285

23  CoreFoundation                      0x043e183f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15

24  CoreFoundation                      0x043e11cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235

25  CoreFoundation                      0x043fe29e __CFRunLoopRun + 910

26  CoreFoundation                      0x043fdac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467

27  CoreFoundation                      0x043fd8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123

28  Foundation                          0x0360e9c5 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 284

29  Foundation                          0x035aa8d1 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 82

30  MyApp                            0x00287164 +[GAI threadMain:] + 70

31  Foundation                          0x03609597 -[NSThread main] + 76

32  Foundation                          0x036094f6 __NSThread__main__ + 1275

33  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x040015b7 _pthread_start + 344

34  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x03febdce thread_start + 34
```

)

What's the problem?